# Ignore tags should include partial or related tags as well

Tags: feature-request, tags, ignored-tags, ambiguous-tags

When I add a tag to "Ignored tags", for example if I add '[android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)' tag, all the related tags (for example '[android-xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-xml)') should also be ignored, unless I explicitly added the related tag to "Interesting tags".

Maybe this option should be on-demand/configurable, but I am sure many users are facing this issue.

Maybe should also be the same with "Interesting tags" (i.e. include related-tags in interesting tags).

Answer (score 10):

This is already supported.  You can use wildcards in the interesting and ignored tags.  If you add `android*` as a tag to your ignored list, it will ignore `android`, `android-xml`, `android-etc`, etc.

Comment: The thing is the system has to be smart and aware of tag-relations, for instance, I want to filter 'java' related tags, but I still want to have javascript not ignored.
ITOH, I don't want to have javascript* in my "Interesting tags" either.
Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: @Shimmy, Tags are not *related* like this though.  Yes, the naming may follow a pattern, but there is no tag hierarchy.  You could add `java` and `java-*` to your ignored tags to leave out special handling for javascript.